# SQL Bigint to int64 to timestamp yielding incorrect date

Tags: python

I am writing a script to output csv's that need to have the date of the execution time in YYYYMMDD format as part of the filename.
the execution_timestamp is pulled through JDBC and ends up in my DataFrame 
as int64.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from dateutil import parser
```

Input:

```
    x = pd.DataFrame([1493293503289], columns=['EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP'])
    ts= x['EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP']
    ts
```

Output:

```
    0    1493293503289
    Name: EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP, dtype: int64
```

I have written the following code, where I convert to a pandas 
DataFrame -> timestamp ->parsed YYYYMMDD

Input:

```
    df=pd.DataFrame(ts) # create pd data frame 
    ts_conv = pd.to_datetime(df['EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP'], unit='ns')[0]
    parser.parse(str(ts_conv)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Output:

```
    '19700101'
```

But  `ts_conv` = `Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:24:53.293503289')`

I know that the actual execution time is `'2017-04-27-11.45.03'`
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to convert this to the appropriate date.

Comment: Seems like you're using wrong unit, try with  `unit='ms'`.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion from @gseva setting `unit='ms'` the parse provides the correct `YYYYMMDD` string. The units were in nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.

Input:

```
    ts_conv = pd.to_datetime(df['EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP'], unit='ms')[0]
    parser.parse(str(ts_conv)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Output:

```
    '20170427'
```